# How can I ignore whitespace when using a sedfile to make recursive changes in a directory?

Tags: linux, sed, find

I have a directory consisting of 102 sub-directories with 1590 files.
I attempted to run the below command recursively against all files, including files with whitespace in the name to change a list of 400 tags from `#tag` to `[[link]].`

```
find . -name '*.md' | xargs sed -i -f sedfile *.md
```

It works only for files that do not have whitespace in the file names. The sedfile is formatted as `s/#tag/[[link]]/g`

```
sed: can't read ./4.Programming/G-Code/List: No such file or directory
sed: can't read of: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Common: No such file or directory
sed: can't read G-Code: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Commands: No such file or directory
sed: can't read and: No such file or directory
sed: can't read What: No such file or directory
sed: can't read They: No such file or directory
sed: can't read Mean.md: No such file or directory
```

The file name is 4.Programming/G-Code/List of Common G-Code Commands and What They Mean.md.

I had previously used

```
find . -type f -name "*.md" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/#tag/[[link]]/g'
```

to make the changes individually, but I am not looking forward to manually changing 390+ more.

When I attempt to combine these two

```
find . -name '*.md' print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -f sedfile *.md
```

I get

```
find: paths must precede expression: `print0`
```

The articles I have found thus far in my research show how to make multiple changes to a single file or a single change to multiple files.
How can I edit either of the two examples to cover *.md files in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo: you use `print0` instead of `-print0`.

You also don't need the `*.md`, because `xargs` is providing the filenames.

This should work:

```sh
find . -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -f sedfile
```

You could also use `-exec` instead:

```sh
find . -name '*.md' -exec sed -i -f sedfile {} +
```